# How to re-select a previously selected region in visual mode?

Tags: visual-mode, selection

I often select a region in visual mode for properly indenting it. However, after pressing for example `3>`, visual mode exits and the selection disappears.

How can I re-select the previously selected region, so that I may further edit it?

Answer (score 5):

If I get you right it is `gv`.

You can also remap `>` and `<`:

```
xnoremap > >gv
xnoremap < <gv
```

Comment: xnoremap, please